# Unable to change Git Shell Client on Windows 10 Using GitHub For Windows client

Tags: git, bash, shell, powershell, windows-10

I am currently using the Github Client for Windows which defaults the Git Shell to Windows PowerShell. I would like to use a different shell which is Git Bash (MingW32).

I changed it on the settings page of Github GUI but then when I launch the GitShell using the shortcut in start menu it opens the PowerShell still. any suggestions how I could change this to Git Bash

Answer (score 0):

Git actually ships with plugins for several shells, but it’s not turned on by default. First, you need to get a copy of the [contrib/completion/git-completion.bash](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash) file out of the Git source code. Copy it somewhere handy, like your home directory, and add this to your `.bashrc`

```
. ~/git-completion.bash
```

Once that’s done, change your directory to a git repository, and type:

```
$ git chec<tab>
```

…and Bash will auto-complete to git checkout. This works with all of Git’s subcommands, command-line parameters, and remotes and ref names where appropriate.

It’s also useful to customize your prompt to show information about the current directory’s Git repository. This can be as simple or complex as you want, but there are generally a few key pieces of information that most people want, like the current branch, and the status of the working directory. To add these to your prompt, just copy the [contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh) file from Git’s source repository to your home directory, add something like this to your `.bashrc`:

```
. ~/git-prompt.sh
export GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=1
export PS1='\w$(__git_ps1 " (%s)")\$ '
```

The `\w` means print the current working directory, the `\$` prints the `$` part of the prompt, and `__git_ps1 " (%s)"` calls the function provided by `git-prompt.sh` with a formatting argument. Now your bash prompt will look like this when you’re anywhere inside a Git-controlled project: